# Laravel 4 - Use a controller action in other controllers?

Tags: php, oop, laravel, laravel-4

well I had a few controllers that were doing my jobs, now I created a few more controllers; some where in middle of an action in new controller, I just remembered that I've written the proper code in old controllers.

so for e.g. in oldController@handyAction

```
some_good_codez();
```

and in newController@newAction

```
$myOldController = Load::controller('oldController'); // I wish Laravel had this?
$myOldController->handyAction();
```

Comment: i don't understand using controller's action in another. if lots of controller uses the same method, include it in base controller or create a class for it and then call it.

Comment: @itachi not lots of controllers, for example 2 controllers want to use a full non static class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is wrong. Controllers have to have just one responsibility: receive a http request, get some data from your models and pass it away to a view. If your controllers have to 'talk' with another controller, it's probably because you're processing data on them, or reading data through them and you shouldn't because to process data is the responsibility of models not controllers.

First, take a look at [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) and [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). If you can buy [Taylor Otwell's book: Laravel: From Apprentice To Artisan](https://leanpub.com/laravel), do it, it will give you a good idea of how to implement SOLID principles in Laravel.

Then, if you **really** need to use a method on two different controllers, create a new class and use this class on both controllers. Just refactor your code to do something like this:

```
class MyController1 extends Controller {

    public function __construct(MyClass $class)   
    {
        $this->myClass = $class;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->myClass->doWhatever();
    }

}

class MyController2 extends Controller {

    public function __construct(MyClass $class)   
    {
        $this->myClass = $class;
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->myClass->doWhatever();
    }

}

class MyClass {

    public function doWhatever()
    {
        return 'done';
    }

}
```

This is still wrong, but a little better.

What's even better is to process your data in a data repository, so take a look at the Repository Pattern,  [this Taylor's video](http://vimeo.com/53029232) will give you a nice idea of how you do it. It talks about testability, but it's not just that, you can create domain repositories and mix two or more models inside it and process data from those models in one class. A code using the Repository pattern would looke more like:

Create an interface (contract):

```
interface MyDataRepository {

    public function getInfoA();
    public function getInfoB($dataA);

}
```

Create a class that implements this interface

```
class MyData implements MyDataRepository {

    public function __construct(MyModelA $dataA, MyModelB $dataB)   
    {
        $this->dataA = $dataA;
        $this->dataB = $dataB;
    }

    public function getInfoA()
    {
        return $this->dataA->processData();
    }

    public function getInfoB($dataA)
    {
        return $this->dataB->processData( $this->getInfoA() );
    }

}
```

**[edit]**

Think of a repository as a bag, where you can put everything you need and extract what you need from it.

In this repository we are using 2 models (MyModelA e MyModelB), instantiated by the Laravel's IoC Container, and in the method `getInfoB` the repository is using both to generate data and pass it back to the controller.

This all come from Domain Driven Development. A Domain is a complex model, like Order, that's built using data from orders, users, items, shippings and payments tables. Without all this information you don't really have an Order to show on your payment page, so you create an Order Repository and mix all your ORM in one class, wich has the single resposibility to get data from those tables and send it back to your controller.

**[/edit]**

You'll have to tell Laravel to instantiate that class when it needs an instance of your Interface:

```
App::bind('MyDataRepository', 'MyData ');
```

This is done only when you are using interfaces, here we are doing the same using a concrete class and we don't need to inform anything, Laravel knows what to do:

```
public function __construct(MyClass $class)   
{
    $this->myClass = $class;
}
```

And create your controllers using the repository:

```
    class MyController1 extends Controller {

    public function __construct(MyDataRepository $data)   
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->data->getInfoA();
    }

}

class MyController2 extends Controller {

    public function __construct(MyDataRepository $class)   
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->myClass->getInfoB();
    }

}
```

Laravel will automatically instantiate an instance of your class, you don't need to do anything else to make it work.

Comment: so i should write data processors in models? in codeigniter I could write any kind of process on data and then pass it to the controller, but here in laravel I feel that I'm limited to a ORM and its default actions, it has a app/model directory but models extend Eloquent not for example baseModel. so here I can do CRUD on database, not processing the data before passing it to the controler. again in CI there was a $this->load('modelName') method that loaded the model class right in controller. I think these differences are making me ask such aberrant questions.

Comment: You can (pretty much) do whatever you need in Laravel, but you have differentiate `what you can do` from `what you should do`. And you don't need to 'load' anything, composer autoloading system takes care of everthing to you, you just use them and they will be loaded automatically.

Comment: yes, so `should I` create a file in app/models and extend Eloquent and add actions I need to that class? shouldn't any model be linked to one table?  what if I needed few db tables in that model? can I ( Should I!) use a model's action in another model?!!

Comment: That's where a repository enters, think of a repository as a bag, where you can put everything you need and extract what you need from it. In that repository I wrote, we have 2 models (MyModelA e MyModelB), in the method (getInfoB) the repository is using both to generate data and pass it back to the controller. This come from Domain Driven Development. A Domain is a complex model, like Order, when you need data from the order, user, items, payment, everything togheter to show on your payment page, you just create an Order Repository and mix them all in one class.

Comment: Good write up, but I believe you'd want to `implements MyDataRepository` rather than `extends`