# Laravel using a controller in an other controller

Tags: class, laravel, controller

I want to use the data from 1 controller in an other controller, like this

```
class CompanyController extends Controller
{
    public function getCompaniesForUser()
    {
        $companies = $this->company->get();

        return $companies; // This does work good and returns the values
    }
}



class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function test()
    {
        $companies = $company->getCompaniesForUser();

        return $companies; 
    }
}
```

but how do i get acces to the $company->getCompaniesForUser();  in the User class ?

Comment: instead of this approach, create a repository and do an injection and retrieve the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

in laravel 4.2

`App::make('CompanyController')->getCompaniesForUser();`

in laravel 5

`\App::make('App\Http\Controllers\DocControllerCompanyController')->getCompaniesForUser();`

---

**BUT** Suggest you read this answer [Laravel 4 - Use a controller action in other controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19495106/laravel-4-use-a-controller-action-in-other-controllers)

Using repository is a better way!

Comment: $id = \App::make('App\Http\Controllers\UserTypeController')->test();

This does work.. but i think there should be a smarter option.. without using repository.

Comment: Do it like this : `$userTypeCtrlObj = \App::make('App\Http\Controllers\UserTypeController'); ` `$id = $userTypeCtrlObj->test();`  I think it will better.